# How to copy value in Numeric Indicator to Numeric Control in LabVIEW program?

Tags: labview

How to copy value from numeric indicator to Numeric control in Laview program? That is Numerical Control should use the value that is displayed in the indicator.

Comment: Khachik: Why are you doing this? If you have the value on a wire somewhere enough to update the indicator, use that wire to do the operation that you're doing instead of getting a control involved at all. I hate to answer so many of the StackOverflow questions with "you could do that but why are you even trying", but so many of these questions imply that you're probably designing some very brittle software. Sure, there are times to update a control from an indicator, no question, but they're not very common, and usually would occur in software for someone who long ago learned how to do it.

Comment: This guy needs to write indicator value on control value, not vice versa. If the question were vice versa I would flag it. But maybe Praveen Kumar has little problem and trying to just solve it and close the deal. Like he is a great -great hardware engineer and do not even want to learn LabVIEW. Anyway if you vote to close the question maybe I will join.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use local variables. Right click on the indicator, create -> local variable.

Then you can change the local indicator to control and wire it to control' local variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do such thing:

1. The easiest way (if you need value from indicator, as an input value to another block - simply put together wire with block input.
2. If it has to be control itself, then use [local variables](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/7585/en/) as @KhachikSahakyan said. What's more after creating local variables you can change it behaviour from read to write by right mouse click.
3. You can also use [shift registers](http://www.ni.com/video/3235/en/) to pass data in some cases.

If such explanation does not solve your problem please provide more info, such as screenshot with fragment of your code.